# If user is in 2 groups and workflow sends an e-mail to both groups, will user get 2 e-mails?

Tags: 2013, workflow, email

I have a workflow that runs whenever a new item is added to a list. It sends an e-mail of the contents of that new list item to two groups:

- Group A
- Group B

If user X is member of both group A and group B, will that mean that user X will receive two e-mails because he is in two groups?

If yes, how do I prevent this? I need a way to check if the user has already received an e-mail through that workflow, or if the user his address is already in the list of recipients or not.

How may I best solve this?

Comment: (let me add with a tiny trace of irony: wouldn't it have been quicker trying it yourself than asking? :-P )

Comment: I didn't think of adding myself to two groups... Yes, that might have been quicker. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a single email (workflow) action that sends to both groups at the same time, i.e. two entries in the TO line, then no, the user will only get one email. From what I can tell, its the Wf engine that sends just the one email, not the mail server blocking it.

If on the other hand, the workflow contains multiple actions, with emails sent to one group in one action and another group in a seperate action, the user will get both emails.

Comment: >its the Wf engine that sends just the one email, not the mail server blocking it. Nope, I tried with both gmail and Exhange before posting my answer and I can confirm it's the mail server that ignores duplicate addresses

Comment: Thanks! I was too scared to publish the workflow since I wasn't sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely he won't receive more than one email.
I'm pretty sure mail servers are clever enough to just send one email per recipient, so you shouldn't really worry about duplicate email addresses